# Can I disable or remove the wso2 identity server resident service provider?

Tags: wso2, service-provider, wso2-identity-server

I'm using WSO2 Identity Server (IS500) with my own SAML2 service provider implementation. Don't want the 'resident service provider' provided by WSO2 Identity Server to be accessible or support any logins. Can I disable a feature to remove this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no any inbound authentication configuration is defined for `Resident Service Provider` by default.  Therefore, it can not be used to authenticate using SAML2/OAuth2/OpenId or any other way.  You can not completely remove the `Resident Service Provider` using management console. but you can find configuration of from the `SP_APP` table in identity database. Basically it is totally fine to keep it.

Comment: The problem is a URL like: "https://localhost/samlsso?spEntityID=some_rubbish" takes me to the login page due to the default service provider. I don't want to get to the login page in this case.